# Setting up ARM Toolchain in Qt Creator (Ardupilot project)

Tags: linux, qt, arm, qt-creator, cross-compiling

I'm starting a drone project based on Ardupilot and trying to build Ardupilot project using **Qt Creator**, following [this instructions](http://ardupilot.org/dev/docs/building-px4-with-qtcreator.html) . I'm working with Ubuntu, BTW.

You've probably find this stupid (cause it probably is), but I'm not able to set up the compiler (in spite of having the instructions):

As suggested, I downloaded the compiler from [here](http://firmware.ardupilot.org/Tools/PX4-tools/), and tried to follow the instructions but after choosing a custom compiler in 'Build & Run', the 'Make path' is driving me crazy and I have no idea of which path is that (in other words, the equivalent to the file 'make.exe' in Windows, see the image attached), since there doesn't seem to be anything similar in the compiler folder and it doesn't seem to refer to the Makefile of the project.

Hope anyone can help me, as you've surely noticed, I'm pretty new to big, real projects and also to Linux itself.
Thanks in advance,

Eduardo

PD:

Instructions provided (both Windows & Linux):
[image: Instructions (both Windows & Linux) I'm supposed to follow]

Linux: Which one is the 'Make path'?
[image: Make path?]

Comment: "I have no idea of which path is that" It is whatever `which make` or `which gmake` prints from the shell, pretty much. If it doesn't find it, then you need to install the make package.

Comment: That seems to partially solve my problem, but I now have to deal with "no rule to make target 'px4-v2'. Stop"; so I'm afraid I'm giving it up for the moment. Thanks anyway, @KubaOber!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The build directory should point to ardupilot/ArduCopter if you are building for Copter

In the example it was pointing to ardupilot

Compiler path: /opt/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_9-2015q3/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc
The make file path: /usr/bin/make

Answer (score 1):

First. What version of qt? If it's 5.7 then the 2015 toolkit won't work. If you're new to Linux then you should definitely stay with a prior version of qt 5.7 until someone has compiled a new toolkit that supports a c++11 compiler.

You don't have enough info on what you're doing to give a good answer though.

What do you need the program to do? If it's Qt3d on Arm then you have a big problem only 5.7 will do.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have installed "Qt Creator 3.0.1 based on Qt 5.2.1".
I just wanted to use Qt Creator as IDE to deal with the project and to compile it instead of using make, but the steps to follow don't seem to be clear enough for me.